# Get PHP callable arguments as an array?

Tags: php, arguments, callable-object

Say I have a callable stored as a variable:

```
$callable = function($foo = 'bar', $baz = ...) { return...; }
```

How would I get 'bar'?

```
if (is_callable($callable)) {
  return func_get_args();
}
```

Unfortunately `func_get_args()` is for the current function, is it possible to get a key value pair of arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$f = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
$params = $f->getParameters();
echo $params[0]->getDefaultValue();
```

Comment: Will `ReflectionFunction` work for any callable? (like class methods and static methods?)

Comment: @SparK  No, it will not work. This was my case. You can take a look at my answer if you still need this.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question because I was looking for getting the arguments for a callable which is not just the function itself. My case is

```
class MyClass{
    public function f(){
        // do some stuff
    }
}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$callable = array($myclass, "f);
```

This is a valid callback in php. In this case the solution given by @Marek does not work.

I worked around with phps [`is_callable`](http://php.net/manual/function.is-callable.php) function. You can get the name of the function by using the third parameter. Then you have to check whether your callback is a function or a (class/object) method. Otherwise the `Reflection`-classes will mess up.

```
if($callable instanceof Closure){
    $name = "";
    is_callable($callable, false, $name);

    if(strpos($name, "::") !== false){
        $r = new ReflectionMethod($name);
    }
    else{
        $r = new ReflectionFunction($name);
    }
}
else{
    $r = new ReflectionFunction($callable);
}

$parameters = $r->getParameters();
// ...
```

This also returns the correct value for `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::isStatic()` even though the `$name` always uses `::` which normally indicates a static function (with some exceptions).

---

Note: In PHP>=7.0 this may be easier using [`Closures`](http://php.net/manual/class.closure.php). There you can do someting like

```
$closure = Closure::fromCallable($callable);

$r = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
```

You may also cause have to distinguish between `ReflectionFunction` and `ReflectionMethod` but I can't test this because I am not using PHP>=7.0.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) to accomplish this, this function will return an array of all defined variables, specifically by accessing the `callable` index from the output array.